# How to use Toast notification as reminder in WP7 using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a reminder control in my code which i want to convert in a toast notification. Can somebody tell me how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native Toast messages are only available to you when you use push notifications, or with background services!

But you can use the [Coding4Fun Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) that has a really cool implementation of the Toast notification!